# Could someone look at my steps and explain where I went wrong?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

Conic: hyperbola, Vertices: $(5,\pi/2)$,$(2,\pi/2)$

What I did is found the center to be $(7/2,π/2)$, so $c=7/2$,
$a=3/2$, $e=(7/2)/(3/2)=7/3$.

Then the horizontal directrix above the pole

$r=(7/3)p/[1+7/3\sinθ]$

$r=7p/[3+7\sin(π/2)]=1$, $p=10/7$

$r=10/[3+7\sinθ]$

Can someone help with where I went wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You are not likely to get a lot of help unless you format this using MathJax. It's pretty hard to read as is. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Is a focus at $0,0$? Knowing only the vertices is not enough.

Comment: Please make the subject line informative about the mathematics in the post, not about you.